# Issues with termcal and extarticle when using a large font

Tags: fontsize, termcal, extsizes

I am using the `termcal` package to create a calendar for a class I teach next semester. This calendar is embedded into the class syllabus, which needs to be typesetted in the 14pt size font. To achieve this, I tried to use the `extarticle` class with 14pt font, but for some reason this adds an empty row into every cell on one of the class days, as well as the warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 30--30
```

However, as the code below shows, I am not adding any extra `\\` anywhere, and
the problem *disappears* once the font is changed back to normal 12pt. Any idea why is this happening? Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{termcal}
\renewcommand{\calprintclass}{}
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{\monthname~\arabic{date}}

\begin{document}

\begin{calendar}{1/17/2022}{4}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
% Description of the Week.
\skipday 
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}
\skipday
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\skipday
\calday[Saturday]{\classday}
\skipday

% Holidays

%Detailed description
%Week1
\caltext{1/20/2022}{Lecture 1}
%Week2
\caltext{1/25/2022}{Problem Session 1}
\caltext{1/27/2022}{Problem Session 2}
\caltext{1/29/2022}{PS 1 due}

\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really related to `extarticle` you see the same with `article`. The `termcal` package adds dozens of spurious space tokens that can in the end produce blank lines and the warnings that you show. This should be reported to the maintainer of the package, it's not really usable as-is.

As a quick fix you can ignore ends of lines while reading the package.

[image]

```
\endlinechar=-1
\usepackage{termcal}
\endlinechar=13
```